# How does one report the row or a specific element(ie rowid) on which an error occured in Postgres/plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

From what I've seen so far on several websites there is no chance to do that. Asking here hoping I missed some crucial information. What I'm trying to do is migrating some tables varying sizes and if the procedure/function gets an error due to anything I want to insert the rowid to the log table. Thanks in advance.

Alper

Comment: You mean GET DIAGNOSTICS? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CALL-STACK

Comment: If I'm not mistaken GET DIASNOSTICS shows the error on the code, whereas I'm trying to find the id of the row in the table. I think it's a more specific information what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just return that id in your error message